# Java - dynamically instantiate abstract subclass

Tags: java

I have the following abstract class

```
public abstract class Document {
  private File file;
  public Document(File f) {
    this.file = f;
  }

  ...

  public abstract String parse();
}
```

Currently, I have two classes that extend `Document`, `JsonDocument` and `XmlDocument`.

In another class, DocumentContent, I have function that iterates through some collection of json and xml files and calls the parse() function to extract certain content.

How can I dynamically instantiate a Document object based on the file extension detected without using a conditional statement?  There will be other file extensions added in the future, I want to avoid the need to update DocumentContent every time a new Document class type is created.

Comment: Just a thought but you could get the file extension (json or xml), uppercase the first letter and concatentate that with "Document" to create the class name and then newInstance() the class - so that would cover you for JsonDocument and XmlDocument.  But this approach forces you into naming the classes <file extension>Document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose to use reflection or not, without reflection you need to design a builder, something like:

```
abstract class DocumentBuilder {
  public abstract Document build(File file);
}

HashMap<String, Builder> builders = new HashMap<String, Builder>();
builders.put("xml", new Builder(){ 
  public build(File file) { return new XMLDocument(file); } 
});

Builder correctBuilder = builders.get("xml");
if (correctBuilder != null)
  return correctBuilder.build()
```

With reflection it would be similar but you will use the newInstance facility given by reflection itself:

```
HashMap<String, Class<? extends Document>> builders = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Document>>();
builders.put("xml", XMLDocument.class);

try {
  Document document = builders.get("xml").newInstance();
}
catch (...)
```

Comment: "*I want to avoid the need to update DocumentContent every time a new Document class type is created.*" How does your solution account for this?

Comment: @Vulcan by having the map/builders outside `DocumentContent`? Or we're talking about magically associating extensions to builders and generate new instances according to a sort of black magic? Like Java that imagines that "xml" extension should be parsed by `XMLDocument` class. Unless you are going to find the class by name and load it (by assuming that they will always correspond), but I'm not going to suggest a so bad choice of design.

Comment: [I like black magic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21594927/1247781), but it is indeed a bad design choice. You've got my +1.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple thing to do is to have a `DocumentFactory` like so:

```
public class DocumentFactory {
  public static Document createFrom(File f) {
    //Produce the right kind of Document based on the File instance
  }
}
```

Use this to create all your `Document`s.

Then since each document knows how to parse itself, you can use polymorphism going forward so long as you always reference each with the `Document` abstraction:

```
for (Document document : documents) {
  document.parse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar requirement few years ago and solved it by using combination of Strategy pattern and Simple Factory pattern (NOT factory method pattern)

```
public class DocumentContent{
   Document document;
    //other code
}
```

So now your DocumentContent is composed of Document. This gives you flexibility to dynamically call methods of Document class. I will suggest you better have Document as interface which gets implemented in sub classes. You can instantiate like below :

```
 document = new JsonDocument();
 //OR  
 document = new XmlDocument();
```

And based on file extension you can instantiate either of classes. You can easily add / remove new Documents without much changes.